# CKEditor Carrierwave Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, carrierwave, cloudinary

I'm trying to get CKEditor to work with Carrierwave and Cloudinary. So far, non-CKEditor enabled views with a regular file upload field are working perfectly with Carrierwave & Cloudinary. However, when I try to upload a file in CKEditor and "Send it to the Server" I'm getting a `NoMethodError - undefined method 'each' for "image/jpeg":String:`

Prior to removing the local storage config from the CKEditor classes it was working, but saving the file locally.

**Here is my current CKEditor uploader:**

```
class CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave

  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.attachment_file_types
  end
end
```

**Log file:**

```
Started POST "/ckeditor/pictures?CKEditor=subsection_content&CKEditorFuncNum=3&langCode=en&authenticity_token=5Bt06UwjUD%2FEdLFANBmZojdv8Hvn2GbQRLvC6h11Dd8%3D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-20 15:44:18 -0700
Processing by Ckeditor::PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff742c77018 @original_filename="pic1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"pic1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0t/l1qc3j596v77_z3s8f2pm75w0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130620-18566-i0av53>>, "CKEditor"=>"subsection_content", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"3", "langCode"=>"en", "authenticity_token"=>"5Bt06UwjUD/EdLFANBmZojdv8Hvn2GbQRLvC6h11Dd8="}
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for "image/jpeg":String:
  (gem) cloudinary-1.0.59/lib/cloudinary/carrier_wave/process.rb:100:in `block in transformation'
```

Any ideas appreciated!

**UPDATE - Working config from Tal Lev-Ami answer**

This is my current, working `ckeditor_picture_uploader.rb` file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  # Include RMagick or ImageScience support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # include CarrierWave::ImageScience

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  # def store_dir
  #   "uploads/ckeditor/pictures/#{model.id}"
  # end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  [:extract_content_type, :set_size, :read_dimensions].each do |method|
    define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
      send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
      {}
    end
    alias_method_chain method, :cloudinary
  end

  process :read_dimensions

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [118, 100]
  end

  version :content do
    process :resize_to_limit => [800, 800]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.image_file_types
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add the following code to your CkPictureUploader/CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader:

```
[:extract_content_type, :extract_size, :extract_dimensions].each do |method|
  define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
    send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
    {}
  end
  alias_method_chain method, :cloudinary
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Ckeditor was updated so this may need to be extract_size and extract_dimensions depending on ckeditor gem version

Commit Where it was changed:
https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/4e6d8413cc71f40d2d58ab3d0cb8dad19dd96894/lib/ckeditor/backend/carrierwave.rb

ie:

```
[:extract_content_type, :extract_size, :extract_dimensions].each do |method|
  define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
  send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?  (CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
    {}
 end
  alias_method_chain method, :cloudinary
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have issue with the combination of these gems. Edit your `CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader` to look similar to this:

```
class CkeditorAttachmentFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  [:extract_content_type, :extract_size, :extract_dimensions].each do |method|
    define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
      send(:"#{method}_without_cloudinary") if self.file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
      {}
    end
    alias_method :"#{method}_without_cloudinary", method
    alias_method method, :"#{method}_with_cloudinary"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.attachment_file_types
  end
end
```

After that, you will find another error.
I found that in [Ckeditor::AssetResponse#asset_url](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/ckeditor/asset_response.rb#L89) 
method, the `asset` object is not reloaded, so `asset.content_url` will always be nil thus caused the error. I fixed it like this:

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  ...
  def url_content
    url(:content) || begin
      if persisted?
        reload
        url(:content)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And similarly for `Ckeditor::AttachmentFile` class if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my comment here

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/670#issuecomment-301218366

```
# encoding: utf-8
class CkeditorPictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  process :extract_dimensions

  [:extract_content_type, :extract_size, :extract_dimensions].each do |method|
    define_method :"#{method}_with_cloudinary" do
      send :"#{method}_without_cloudinary" if self.file.is_a? CarrierWave::SanitizedFile
      {}
    end
    alias_method_chain method, :cloudinary
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [118, 100]
  end

  version :content do
    process :resize_to_limit => [800, 800]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    Ckeditor.image_file_types
  end
end
```