# CKEditor, CarrierWave, Cloudinary image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, cloudinary

I have a Rails 4 app, that I'm trying to add CKEditor to for a blog creation page. I actually have a few different issues with it, but I'll stick to just the one here.

Currently I have a `Image` model where I am able to successfully upload images to Cloudinary with no problems. Works perfectly.

My gemfile:

```
gem "ckeditor"
gem "mini_magick"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "cloudinary"
```

I have also ran the ckeditor rails command:

`rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave`

Since I've been stuck on this for a few days now I don't remember all the steps I took, but I believe at this point I was able to link to images and I believe maybe even store them locally. Great, except I want to store them on Cloudinary...

Off the top of my head I remember I've tried, mirroring my `ImageUploader.rb` file which didn't work, and I know I tried to just swap out `CKEditorPictureUploader` inside of `models/ckeditor/picture.rb`
I have also came across a similar StackOverflow post here:

[CKEditor Carrierwave Cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225138/ckeditor-carrierwave-cloudinary)

Trying the suggestion in this StackOverflow post, it acts like it's going to upload an image to the server, but then it just hangs there forever. In chrome I was not able to see any errors, so I thought maybe it's just being slow...but I left it overnight, and came back to the same spot. So I went over to firefox and opened up firebug, and noticed that it was trying to post but it was getting a `500 internal server error` with the suggestion of the linked SO post. When I click on the `POST pictures?CKEDITOR=blog...` error in firebug I get:

```
NoMethodError in Ckeditor::PicturesController#create

undefined method `each' for "image/png":String
```

I am totally stuck here...

Comment: It is clear from the error message that `PicturesController#create` method expects some sort of collection, probably a hash (filename => mime), but you're passing a string.

Comment: Can you make sure that you have updated the ckeditor_picture_uploader with the lines from the answer to the question you referenced? They seem to be working with the latest ckeditor.

Comment: They are there. When I try to upload an image using the "image info" section(the initial image upload section that pops up, where you can resize) it just sits there and hangs, and never uploads...If I go to the upload section and try to "send it to the server" i get the error...I even tried copy and pasting his supposed working answer...same stuff :\

Comment: I just tried with a clean Rails 4.0.2 + ckeditor 4.0.10 + cloudinary 1.0.70 project. Adding the lines as suggested in [CKEditor Carrierwave Cloudinary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225138/ckeditor-carrierwave-cloudinary) to CkeditorPictureUploader was enough to get it working. Can you try on a dummy app and if it still fails post it?

Comment: hmmm, well that is weird. I made a dummy app and was able to successful upload images as well...so now I'm REALLY confused...haha

Comment: ugh...well out of frustration I ran a `rails destroy ckeditor:install` deleted the table from the db, ran a bundle update (cause i did that in the dummy app), in eclipse i ran a "clean" though I'm not sure if that did anything, but then I ran a rails g `ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave` copied the files directly from the dummy app you asked me to make (which I copied from my project originally) then restarted the rails server, and everything seems to be working just fine now. Awesome, but i still wish I knew what caused it though...